# While calling the Discount method its not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, inheritance

Calling the `discount` method of parent class in the following example throws `AttributeError`

```
class Dress:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):

        for key,value in kwargs.items():
            setattr(self,key,value)

        def discount(self):
            self.price = self.price - 10

class Shirt(Dress):
    def __init__(self):
        attr = {
            "color" : "red",
            "price" : "50",
            "size" : "medium"
            }

        super().__init__(**attr)

>>> a= Shirt()
>>> a.color
'red'
>>> a.discount()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#18>", line 1, in <module>
    a.discount()
AttributeError: 'Shirt' object has no attribute 'discount'
```

Comment: Welcome to SO ,please foramt your code properly and also descrribe your problem.

Comment: I can't really tell what is the problem, but just make sure that `discount(self)` is defined in the class, and not inside `init`. Also, I think you meant `__init__`. You really should edit the code formatting

Comment: The problem is the indentation, `discount` is a function inside `Dress.__init__()`, it is clear after you fix the formatting. But notice that the class variable `price` is a string so `discount` will throw an error anyway.

Comment: it worked....intendation problem

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not just the indentation. `__init__` functions were declared incorrectly. `price` value was string, therefore `discount` caused further error. Here is the corrected code:

```
class Dress: 
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        for key, value in kwargs.items():
            setattr(self,key,value)

    def discount(self):
        self.price = self.price - 10

class Shirt(Dress): 
    def __init__(self): 
        attr = { "color" : "red", "price" : 50, "size" : "medium" }
        super(Shirt, self).__init__(**attr)

a = Shirt()
print(a.price)
a.discount()
print(a.price)
```

Also defining a shirt class just to put some hardcoded values inside, is not a clever idea. Make the constructor of `Shirt` catch those values.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Dress:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        for key,value in kwargs.items():
            setattr(self,key,value)

    #the indentation of discount definition was incorrect
    def discount(self):
        self.price = self.price - 10

class Shirt(Dress):
    def __init__(self):
        attr = {
            "color" : "red",
            "price" : 50,
            "size" : "medium"
        }

    super().__init__(**attr)
```

Answer (score 0):

There was an indentation error, that's why your function discount() wasn't working.

```
class Dress:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        for key,value in kwargs.items():
            setattr(self,key,value)

    def discount(self):
        self.price = self.price - 10

class Shirt(Dress):
    def __init__(self):
        attr = {
            "color" : "red",
            "price" : "50",
            "size" : "medium"
            }

        super().__init__(**attr)
```